# How to add attributes to re.Match object?

Tags: python

I am trying to add an attribute to an `re.Match` object:

```
match = self.regEx.search(self.buffer)
if match:
    match.type = MatchType.Message
```

but it gives me an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 're.Match' object has no attribute 'type'
```

I also tried `setattr(match, 'type', MatchType.Message)` but it produces the same error.

- Why is this error thrown?
- Is there a "simple" way around it?

**Edit**:
Using `match['type'] = MatchType.Message` gives:

```
TypeError: 're.Match' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: try to set type ```match['type'] = MatchType.Message```. But why you need it?

Comment: @VolArt That gives a TypeError (see my edit). I "need" it because I am having multiple regular expressions and a method that matches all of them and then returns the first match within the string. But the caller also needs to know which regex matched. But it seems I have to do it differently.

Comment: Yes it is bad idea to change re.Match object and attach them any custom attribute ```match.type = MatchType.Message```. Need change logic. Try to use native methods that has in object.

Comment: @Ignitor There are different workaround, for example you can wrap it in a tuple or dict instead. The question is why you would want to set that attribute in the first place. Probably there are more appropriate ways of dealing with it.